# Pandas importing from 12 excel documents - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'x'

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

Python novice- I've attempted to trial and error through solutions that came up when I searched the above error. Whenever I've used pandas in the past, I've used while loops to go through each individual file before opening a new file to add information to my dataframe. Here, my goal is simply to get last week's data from different sectors via pdr.over_ride().

It downloads the files properly, but when trying to assign columns as a variable (works when I do them one at a time via while loop), I keep getting the **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'x'** error.

I don't see where I'm asking python to grab a file named 'x', and have searched stackexchange and tried looking through pandas documentation to find a solution. Any help or a point in the direction towards a solution, or an alternative method would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the full error, and then my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/jchil/Desktop/python/Finance/MarketWatch.py", line 45, in <module>
    df0 = pd.read_excel(savename[0], 'Sheet1')
  File "C:\Users\jchil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\jchil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 824, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "C:\Users\jchil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 21, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\jchil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\jchil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 36, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\jchil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 111, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'x'
```

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from money import Money
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import sys
import re
import os

spiders = {
    '^GSPC': 'S&P 500', 'xlp': 'consumer staples select sector', 'xly': 'consumer discretionary select sector',
    'xlk': 'technology select sector', 'xlv': 'health care select sector', 'xli': 'industrials select sector',
    'xlu': 'utilities select sector', 'xlb': 'materials select sector', 'xle': 'energy select sector',
    'xlf': 'financial select sector', 'xlre': 'real estate select sector', 'xlc': 'communication services select sector'}

keys, values = zip(*spiders.items())
print ("keys : ", str(keys))

begin = "2020-05-01"
through = "2020-06-01"

yf.pdr_override()

collecting = True
savelist = []
j = 0

while collecting == True:
    #index = pdr.get_data_yahoo(keys[j], start=begin, end=through)
    #saver = index.to_excel(str(keys[j]) + '.xlsx')
    savename = str(keys[j]) + '.xlsx'
    savelist.append(savename)
    print(savelist)
    j = j + 1

    if j == len(values):
        collecting = False

df0 = pd.read_excel(savename[0], 'Sheet1')
df1 = pd.read_excel(savename[1], 'Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(savename[2], 'Sheet1')
df3 = pd.read_excel(savename[3], 'Sheet1')
df4 = pd.read_excel(savename[4], 'Sheet1')
df5 = pd.read_excel(savename[5], 'Sheet1')
df6 = pd.read_excel(savename[6], 'Sheet1')
df7 = pd.read_excel(savename[7], 'Sheet1')
df8 = pd.read_excel(savename[8], 'Sheet1')
df9 = pd.read_excel(savename[9], 'Sheet1')
df10 = pd.read_excel(savename[10], 'Sheet1')
df11 = pd.read_excel(savename[11], 'Sheet1')

date = df0['Date']
snp = df0['Adj Close']
xlp = df1['Adj Close']
xly = df2['Adj Close']
xlk = df3['Adj Close']
xlv = df4['Adj Close']
xli = df5['Adj Close']
xlu = df6['Adj Close']
xlb = df7['Adj Close']
xle = df8['Adj Close']
xlf = df9['Adj Close']
xlre = df10['Adj Close']
xlc = df11['Adj Close']'''
```

Comment: I think you want `df0 = pd.read_excel(savelist[0], 'Sheet1')`. Note the difference between `savelist` and `savename`

Answer (score 0):

i think you want the accumulator variable `savelist` for each of the read_excel statements, not `savename` which is the variable youre using inside the loop. as written, this will take each character of the last value of `savename` and interpret it as a filename.

Comment: thanks so much, I'll try it first thing in the morning